# Added execution time in discord.js bot console

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, discord.js, bots

I created a discord.js bot that works all the time. In the terminal where the bot is running I would like the running time of the bot since it started up to be displayed below "I am connected !".

Here is part of my console code :

```
client.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('I am connected !');
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: on outer scope (i.e on boot) create a `new Date()`, then in your callback compare a `new Date()` with the one created on boot, fancify into the format you want

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Lawrence Cherone, you can use a date in the top of the file to compare with one on ready. For example:

```
const startup = new Date()
// Other code...

client.on("ready" => {
  const ready = new Date()
  const diff = ready.getTime() - startup.getTime()
  console.log(`I am connected! Startup took ${diff}ms`)
})
```

If you want the time in a format other than milliseconds, you can use [ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms), a tiny library written by Vercel devs on npm which converts milliseconds into human-friendly timestamps.